# add this object into array

Tags: javascript, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

```
for (var i=0; i<songList.length; i++){
        test.init({
        });
}

var test = {
    init: function (params) {
        var my = this;

        var backend = WaveSurfer.Audio;

        if (!params.predrawn) {
            backend = WaveSurfer.WebAudio;
        }
        var id = playList.length;
        this.id = id;

        this.backend = Object.create(backend);
        this.backend.init(params);

        this.drawer = Object.create(WaveSurfer.Drawer);
        this.drawer.init(params);

        this.backend.bindUpdate(function () {
            my.onAudioProcess();
        });

        this.bindClick(params.canvas, function (percents) {
            my.playAt(percents);
        });

    playList.push(my);
```

When I debug this script: my id is 0 for the first element; but when I go into the second loop suddenly both ids become 1. How is this possible?

[image]

Comment: So... you add an element to playlist, and you're confused that it's 1 element larger?

Comment: No i'm confused about the fact that they have both id:1 when I expect the first to be 0 and the second to be 1

Comment: @ThomasVerbeke code has 'this.id = id' which sets id as 1 for my

Comment: @ThomasVerbeke: `this` and therefore `my` will be a reference to the same `test` object in every call.

Answer (score 4):

Because first time playList is empty that why length of playlist is zero but  after init call it has one items so length of playList become 1 for second init call so value of id depends on number of init call.

Since you are not creating any new object so every time `my` will reference same object. so any change in `my` will reflect in all pushed items in playlist.

Modified code: if you want add new item on each init call

```
var test = {
    init: function (params) {
        var my = {};

        var backend = WaveSurfer.Audio;

        if (!params.predrawn) {
            backend = WaveSurfer.WebAudio;
        }
        var id = playList.length;
        my.id = id;

        my.backend = Object.create(backend);
        my.backend.init(params);

        my.drawer = Object.create(WaveSurfer.Drawer);
        my.drawer.init(params);

        my.backend.bindUpdate(function () {
            my.onAudioProcess();
        });

        my.bindClick(params.canvas, function (percents) {
            my.playAt(percents);
        });

    playList.push(my);
```